# jquery code that makes automatic picture change to next

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I don`t exactly know how to ask this but I will try, I want that image every 3 seconds changes to next image with jquery.

I didn`t found any information on this topic.

Comment: Without any code, we can't help much, only guess. Please see this article: [How to create a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: You seem to describe a carousel, you could look for "jquery carousel"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well since there is no code posted i dont think there can be a answer that completely satisfies you.

But you can use [setInterval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/setInterval), in order to call the function  that changes picture every 3 seconds.

I suggest you look up `Image Slider` on the internet for effects that you want.

you can also check [Carousel](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/carousel/), that you can use it with `setInterval`.

Comment: I will look in that, thanks for more information on this topic!

Answer (score 0):

I had done something like that some 2/3 years ago but I think I can recollect this from my memory, for this I stored the image in a local directory and declared an array something like below

```
const arr={ 'path1', 'path2', 'path3', 'path4'}
```

and  then use setinterval for every 3 seconds

```
setInterval(function () {
   $('#imgTagId').attr('src', arr[i]);
   if(i>=arr.length)
       i=0
   else
       i+1
}, 3000);
```

this is how I used it, it might be wrong but worked for me

let me know if it worked

Comment: nope, doesn`t work

Comment: share the code you have written

Comment: where are you storing your image

Comment: and what error are you getting with the above code, I might help it out

Comment: I got an error because of this character , but other comment reminded me that bootstrap exists because I forgot about that lol.

Comment: i dont have enough reputation :(